# How to configure Tomcat 7 support thread per request

Tags: tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I heard that Tomcat support servlet 3.0 and thread per request. 
And I don't experiment like this:
[Servlet seems to handle multiple concurrent browser requests synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011138/java-servlet-concurrent-request)

I expected that Thread.sleep wouldn't block other requests even made from the same browser window, but it does. The output is still not in concurrent way.

So how to configure Tomcat 7 support thread per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fighting against HTTP keep-alive here. Your browser and Tomcat will act to conserve TCP connections and send multiple requests over a single connection. But why would you sleep in a request thread at all? The server is supposed to service requests, not go to sleep.

Comment: Sleeping in a request was meant to mock blocking io. (btw is sleeping works the same way as IO operation?) But yeah, I got myself confused. It's nothing to do with servlet 3.0 async io nor thread per request. It's just HTTP 1.1 keep-alive.