# Is HttpSessionAttributeListener processed async?

Tags: java, session, servlets, listener

Consider algorithm:

1. a new attribute is added to the session `session.setAttribute("myObject", new Object);`
2. [HttpSessionAttributeListener#attributeAdded](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html#attributeAdded(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent)) is invoked
3. code after `session.setAttribute`

Does `HttpSessionAttributeListener#attributeAdded` block `session.setAttribute` or listener code invokes async?

Answer (score 3):

Listener is invoked in the same thread as `set|get|removeAttribute()` is invoked.

So, the only race condition may occur when `setAttribute()` is invoked in another thread. Given that the average servlet container uses a [single thread per HTTP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011138/servlet-seems-to-handle-multiple-concurrent-requests-synchronously) (and thus not necessarily per HTTP request when HTTP 1.1 `keep-alive` is on), then this race condition may occur when the enduser spawns two completely separate browser instances (not windows/tabs) and copies the session cookie from the one to the other and then simultaneously fires a request from both clients on that session triggering the `setAttribute()` method in server.

This is however not an usual real world case. Moreover, the container will all by itself worry about threadsafety of accessing the `HttpSession` instance. This is specified in chapter 7.7.1 of [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ## 7.7.1 Threading Issues
>
> Multiple servlets executing request threads may have active access to the same
>   session object at the same time. **The container must ensure that manipulation of
>   internal data structures representing the session attributes is performed in a thread
>   safe manner.** The Developer has the responsibility for thread safe access to the
>   attribute objects themselves. This will protect the attribute collection inside the
>   `HttpSession` object from concurrent access, eliminating the opportunity for an
>   application to cause that collection to become corrupted.

So your only concern is the threasafety of the attribute itself. E.g. if it's an `ArrayList`, and you worry about its threadsafety, you'd likely want to wrap it in [`Collections#synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 1):

Its a SYNC Process . I just made one sample program.

**JSP Code :**

```
<%
session.setAttribute("ID","12324");
session.setAttribute("ID2","656565");
%>
```

**Listener Code of attributeAdded() Method :**

```
String attributeName = event.getName();
        Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
        System.out.println("Attribute added : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("After Sleep : "+attributeName);
```

> Output :

```
Attribute added : ID : 12324
After Sleep : ID
Attribute added : ID2 : 656565
After Sleep : ID2
```

So you can see that only after printing "After Sleep " for the first id its going to add second id in the session