# Is there only a single HTTP Request associated with a HTTP Connection?

Tags: http, httprequest, httpsession, httpconnection

The source of confusion is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011138/servlet-seems-to-handle-multiple-concurrent-browser-requests-synchronously).

To be honest, I know what is `Http Request`, `Http Session`, but I have never heard this - `Http Connection`. So it boils down to this only. What exactly is the difference b/w `Http Request` & `Http Connection`?

Comment: A connection may be "kept open" for multiple requests in a serial manner  to boost performance.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks. Is there any setting in G Chrome that I can tweak around, so that firing 2 GET requests one after another to the same resource on the server side, uses the very same HTTP Connection.

Comment: Browsers will always try to do that. It is up to the server if the protocol feature is offered.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks once again. But what do I need to look into so as to get convinced that the browser used the same HTTP Connection for the 2 GET requests, fired one after another. I mean is there something meaningful under NETWORK tabs.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to find out... Might be that you have to sniff the traffic on the network layer and check the dynamic port numbers used in the requests.

Comment: @arkascha: Okay, Thank you for all your prompt responses.